# A question regarding inequalities in probablity

Tags: probability

let $A_{i} \subset B_{i} \forall i=1,\ldots n$.
$$\frac{P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})}{P(B_{i}\cap B_{j})} \leq \frac{P(A_i)}{P(B_i)} \forall i,j=1,\ldots n,i\neq j$$
when is the following statement true:
$$\frac{P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_i)}{P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}B_i)}\leq \frac{P(A_i)}{P(B_i)}\forall i=1,\ldots n$$

Comment: In the first inequality you actually don’t need i ≠j since the inequality will hold vacuously otherwise anyway